# actionscript 3 - How do I use this URLRequest script?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I started learning ActionScript 3 a week ago and have stumbled across a huge learning curve. I found this script on the internet:

```
var _loader:URLLoader;
var _request:URLRequest;

function loadData():void {
    _loader = new URLLoader();
    _request = new URLRequest("http://www.travoid.com/game/Purchase.php?gid=1");
    _request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDataFailedToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, onDataFailedToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.VERIFY_ERROR, onDataFailedToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.DISK_ERROR, onDataFailedToLoad);
    _loader.load(_request);
}
function onLoadData(e:Event):void {
    trace("onLoadData",e.target.data);
}
function onDataFailedToLoad(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("onDataFailedToLoad:",e.text);
}
```

This all seems to work and is generating no errors or output, however my issue comes about when I use this next part of code (which I made)

```
function vpBuy(e:MouseEvent):void{
    loadData();
    if (e.target.data == "false") {
        inf_a.visible = true;
        inf_b.visible = true;
        inf_c.visible = true;
        inf_d.visible = true;
        btn_ok.visible = true;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property data not found on
>   flash.display.SimpleButton and there is no default value. at
>   travoid_fla::MainTimeline/vpBuy() onLoadData

The part that is probably throwing this is:

```
if (e.target.data == "false") {
```

I was hoping `e.target.data` was what stored the value on the web page (which displays as false) but apparently not. With the code I found on the internet, what stores the information on the web page?

Thanks, Ethan Webster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's trying to check data before it's loaded. because data loading is a time based process, not instant. so, you've to make your data check condition wait for data really load

i think you should use a callback function for vpBuy from "onLoadData"

or you can try moving your data check conditional into onLoadData function like

```
function onLoadData(e:Event):void {
    trace("onLoadData",e.target.data);
    if (e.target.data == "false")
    {
            inf_a.visible = true;
            inf_b.visible = true;
            inf_c.visible = true;
            inf_d.visible = true;
            btn_ok.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, I added `trace(e.target.data);` in the onLoadData scope and it returns nothing at all. Any other reason? Sorry, I'm a newbie to this.

Comment: what kind of a data you're lookin for inside webpage?
do you wanna check if there is a "page" really or not? Or something else?

Comment: I just tried again in the browser and it worked, using your code - thank you very much.